# Problem running watir-webdriver on Windows 7 with IE9

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'm trying to use watir-webdriver with IE9 on 64bit Windows 7.
When I try to open a new browser I am getting the following error message, any ideas on a solution?

```
C:\watir>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "rubygems"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb(main):003:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new(:ie)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchDriverError: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.
```

I can use watir-webdriver on the same machine okay with Firefox 4, so I'm guess either its and IE9 issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try disabling protected mode as the error message tells you ?

Tools >> Options >> Security >> Untick 'Enable Protected Mode'

This thread on selenium-developers group is relevant to the restrictions with protected mode:
http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/4dd6330f97bd2312/3e904642ac3dac6?q

Also relevant a link to the [Watir FAQ](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/FAQ#FAQ-WhatshouldIdoiftwobrowserwindowsappearwhenrunningatestunderWindowsVista?).

> Try one of these:
>
> - Add your defaut homepage (or 'About:Blank' if you start with a
>     blank page) to the same security group
>     (e.g. 'intranet' or ''trusted sites')
>     as the site you are testing; or
> - Turn off Internet Explorer Protected Mode; or
> - Change your ruby permissions to "run as administrator"; or
> - Disable User Access Control

Comment: Thanks I've just checked at it had been switched on for trusted sites only. Unchecked it and it is launching now, thanks.

Comment: For anyone else having issues with Watir + IE: I was getting a `NoSuchWindowError` (instead of a `NoSuchDriverError`). I'm using Windows 7 x64, Internet Explorer 9, the selenium-webdriver gem v 2.29.0 and IEDriverServer 2.30.1.0. Adding the URL being tested to the trusted sites fixed this error too.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, but I have fixed it within the Automation script by setting IE Capabilities. We can change protected mode settings within the script, before launching the browser. You can try the below code:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.ie(:ignoreProtectedModeSettings => true)
driver = Watir::Browser.new  :ie, :desired_capabilities => caps
```