# Running Test Cases on IE-Verion 8 through Windows XP

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using webDriver version 18,and I am trying to run my testCases on IE version 8 as I have Window XP.But I am facing this problem:-
ERROR: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).How to resolve it,if anybody faced this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

If that doesn't work you will need a new user created by your IT people that does not have protected mode enabled (if you're unable to modify that value in the Options).  I faced the same issue as you, and the above fixed it.  Our IT policy is likely a bit more lenient.

Here are a few resources: [Same issue with .NET](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2018), [same issue with Watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454048/problem-running-watir-webdriver-on-windows-7-with-ie9), [Configuration Settings](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

Comment: Hi Scott,Actually I had already made these changes.Today I had resolved my problem by upgrading the version of Selenium to 2.18 from 2.16.

Answer (score 0):

This is a security option in IE. One solution is "INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORRING_SECURITY_DOMAINS" to set true in DesiredCapabilities.
The other solution is setting the right options in IE:

- Go to InternetOptions in IE
- Click on the security tab
- There you can see the 4 zones

It is not important which security level is set for every zone. it is more important that every zone has the same security level.